# Bumper squeaking on new car

Tags: bumper, squeaking

If I push against the front bumper, near the top of the bumper,  I can hear a distinct squeaking noise. I also hear this noise all the time when the car goes over bumpy roads at specific speeds ~ 40 kph. I've taken it to the dealer and they're unable to fix it. Unfortunately, this is too minor a problem to get any official recourse from the dealer but it bothers me nonetheless.

Any idea on what it could be? The car is VW Polo 6N.

Comment: Is the squeak really coming from the bumper or is it coming from the suspension?

Comment: If this is a "new" car, take it back to the dealership and have them make an adjustment. This is covered under warranty on new cars.

Comment: Definitely the bumper, not the suspension. I press the bumper with my hand in the horizontal direction and I can hear it squeak. Dealership has tried, failed to identify the issue. Sadly, I live in a country where the consumer laws aren't that great so long story short, I need to figure out what the problem is myself.